# Apply two proxy servers to different windows PCs on the same network

Tags: proxy, group-policy

We use microsoft CRM 2011 as our CRM software, Microsoft CRM does not support a proxy.pac file you need to use a static proxy server address for it to work with outlook.

So I need to deploy two different types of proxy servers to the desktops.

What would be the best way to deploy this using group policy.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say CRM doesn't like the PAC file. I also have no idea what you mean by "ip based proxy server." Please explain your environment more fully.

Comment: What I have tried so far is to setup two security groups one called crm and the other proxy then add the relevant users to each group. I then create two group policy, with the different settings, then add the relevant security group to the group policy using security filtering.

Comment: You already said that. You didn't explain what the PAC file is doing (the contents -you know, how it auto-configured the proxy settings for client browsers) or how your proxy/proxies are configured.

Comment: I didn't configure the proxy.pac file I've no control over it, its not supported by the application so my major concern is getting the static and .pac into some form of GP. I tried the above but its not working.

Comment: I'm asking you what's in the PAC file, I'm not asking you to change anything about it. Also, you have not explained what you mean by CRM not supporting the PAC file. One has nothing to do with the other. PAC is simply a means of telling a browser when to use a proxy and which proxy to use, and when to not use a proxy at all (DIRECT).

Comment: Ok don't have the contents of the pac file to hand, will copy and paste here when I have it.